# Passing ouput from model as input pytorch dataloader

Tags: pytorch

I’m doing video prediction frame prediction using LSTM. I have trained the network using input frame at time (t) and target frame at time (t+1).

Now for testing set I want the LSTM to use the output frame from time (t) as a input frame at time (t+1), is it possible to do this using a dataloader?

Comment: yes, but you dont have to use one. Have you tried something that didnt work or what exactly do you want to know? All I can say is: Yes

Comment: How would  you implement this? Are there any examples you can point me to?